# database Error on line .ActiveConnection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, iis-6

We started to recieve odd ole db database errors.

Time out erros came once on while, somethimes once in hour, somethimes many times on hour.

clasic asp returns error from .ActiveConnection line

example:

```
Set valikkohaku = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
valikkohaku.ActiveConnection = MM_tuotemappiadmin_STRING
valikkohaku.Source = "SELECT *  FROM dbo.Rastettyna  where valikkoaktiivinen = '" & thaku.Fields.Item("kieli").Value & "'  "
valikkohaku.CursorType = 0
valikkohaku.CursorLocation = 2
valikkohaku.LockType = 1
valikkohaku.Open()
```

When time out come, time out all are targeted to one SQL server. No specific database. It seems that all databases are like closed for a while. But odd is that most of erros come from line valikkohaku.ActiveConnection. Erros may come from different lines, but allways on line .ActiveConnection. Something freezes SQLserver or connections or something...?

Comment: If you encounter timeouts with just one particular server (out of several) it's practically guaranteed to be either a server-side or a network problem. Did you check the SQL Server logs on that particular server? What do your IIS logs say? What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: Yes. It were some sort of SQL server failure. Chaged active nodes and rebooted server. Now everyting works again.